# Is Microsoft OCR library suitable for handwritten recognition?

Tags: c#, ocr

I need to do a project to capture data from handwritten structured forms. 
I am looking for a OCR SDK with an API preferably in C# or C++. This project will be service in our server, so I would prefer to develop at "low" level instead of purchasing an ended solution like Abby or similar.

Is Microsoft OCR suitable for handwritten structured forms? or is it mainly focused to strokes?

Comment: Very doubtful, google "inkrecognizer class".